# Looking For Azure AD B2C Integration with Liferay sign-IN process Authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, liferay, azure-ad-b2c, openid

how to map the Auth, Discovery end point, jwt, issuer URL from AD B2C to Liferay7.x and capture the user details on successful authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If Liferay supports OIDC, add as an [external IDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).